# JSON.parse for JSON object instead of a string

Tags: javascript, json

I was very comfortable with `JSON.parse` to modify an external API's response string and manipulate it in my own way, like this:

```
JSON.parse(data, (k, v) => {
    // Remove some key values found at any depth of JSON
    if (k === "id") {
        return undefined;
    }
    // Replace some coded strings with their user understandable values
    if (k === "code" && typeof v === 'string') {
        for (let i = 0; i < codesList.length; i++) {
            let item = codesList[i];
            if (item["code"] === v) {
                return item["name"];
            }
        }
    }
    // Do localization of currencies
    if (k === "price") {
        return getSymbolFromCurrency(v.substr(0,3)) + " " + v.substr(3,v.length)
    }
    return v;
});
```

This worked really well when I had a string. Now I want to achieve the same functionality, in an optimized way for object, such as:

```
let object = {
        "keyA" : "valueA",
        "keyB" : "valueB"
    };
```

I assume I can convert the object to a string and then parse it back using the above method, but I think there must be another more optimized solution to this.

Comment: Why is there a distinction between JSON and data? Isn't your data JSON?

Comment: Are you asking how to walk through an object and manipulate its properties?  If so, perhaps show an example of _that_ object and what you've tried with it.

Comment: AFAICS what you call "JSON" is a string. The only easy way to manipulate the data represented by it is to parse it, transform it, then stringify it again. There's no way around that.

Comment: There is no JSON *objects* - only *strings*. You wouldn't say "ATM machine" or "personal PIN number", so stop saying "JSON object"

Comment: @JackParkinson, edited the question so that it makes better sense.

Comment: @naomik, Yup I got some clarity on this, but , you said ' no JSON objects - only strings', so does that mean, let object = {
        "keyA" : "valueA",
        "keyB" : "valueB"
    }; , here object is actually a string?

Comment: You're making it so much harder on yourself. That's an object !

Answer (score 0):

Try Object.entries(), here's 
the documnetation 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

If you have a javascript Object, which is key-value pairs you can use  Object.entries(obj) it will return an array of [key, value] pairs.

Or you can use Object.keys(obj) which will return an array of your object's keys, so you can iterate over the keys and get value, from the object (with obj.key or obj[key]).

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    // Remove some key values found at any depth of JSON
    if (k === "id") {
        return undefined;
    }
    // Replace some coded strings with their user understandable values
    if (k === "code" && typeof v === 'string') {
        for (let i = 0; i < codesList.length; i++) {
            let item = codesList[i];
            if (item["code"] === v) {
                return item["name"];
            }
        }
    }
    // Do localization of currencies
    if (k === "price") {
        return getSymbolFromCurrency(v.substr(0,3)) + " " + v.substr(3,v.length)
    }
    return v;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since already you have the JSON, you can iterate through their keys and values

```
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key,index) {
        // key: the name of the object key
        // index: the ordinal position of the key within the object
        //Using index u can have your value like- Object[index] and then 
        //manipulate as you like
    });
```

Comment: Ravi this does not iterate at the complete depth of the object. It just gives me top level keys.